# How to execute OpenRefine JSON on CSV in Python?

Tags: python, json, csv, openrefine

I am trying to find a Python solution which can execute the following OpenRefine Python commands in JSON without OpenRefine server being on. 
My [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) JSON contains mappings and custom Python commands on each field of any properly formatted CSV file, so this is not a basic JSON reading. 
One example OpenRefine JSON code where only regex mappings

```
[
  {
    "op": "core/text-transform",
    "description": "Text transform on cells in column Sleep using expression jython:import re\n\nvalue = re.sub(\"h0\", \"h\",value)\n\nvalue = re.sub(\"h\",\"*60+\", value)\n\nreturn eval(value)\n\n \nreturn eval(value.replace(\"h\", \"*60+\"));",
    "engineConfig": {
      "mode": "row-based",
      "facets": []
    },
    "columnName": "Sleep",
    "expression": "jython:import re\n\nvalue = re.sub(\"h0\", \"h\",value)\n\nvalue = re.sub(\"h\",\"*60+\", value)\n\nreturn eval(value)\n\n \nreturn eval(value.replace(\"h\", \"*60+\"));",
    "onError": "keep-original",
    "repeat": false,
    "repeatCount": 10
  }
]
```

One solution is to process JSON one by one with each type of element but there may be easier solutions with some packages.

Python: 3.5.2
OS: Debian 9

Answer (score 3):

The [pyrefine](https://github.com/jezcope/pyrefine) project aims to do exactly that. But it is still a work in progress, very few operations are supported. Contributors are welcome!

Comment: Any idea whether there exist a solution in R for the same thing as pyrefine? Most packages I have found are for duplex communication between the client and the OpenRefine server.

Comment: Just, I had completely forgotten the existence of this project!

Comment: @hhh No idea at all, sorry! It would make a lot of sense in R too, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any ready-made solution and I have no idea how to do that. A workaround might be to try to transform the Jython scripts into functions, and then apply them to your csv using pandas.

```
import json
import re

with open("your open refine json", "r") as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

with open("result.py", 'w') as outfile:
    for el in data:
        count = 1
        column=el['columnName']
        expression = el['expression'].replace("jython:", "")
        expression = re.sub(r"\n\n\s?\n?", "\n    ", expression)
        expression = re.sub(r";$", "", expression)
        result = """def function%s(value):\n    %s""" %(count, expression)
        count+=1
        outfile.write(result + 
                      "\n\n" + 
                      "mycsv['%s'] = mycsv['%s'].apply(lambda x: function%s(x))" %(column, column, count-1))
```

result on your Json:

```
def function1(value):
    import re
    value = re.sub("h0", "h",value)
    value = re.sub("h","*60+", value)
    return eval(value)
    return eval(value.replace("h", "*60+")) # is this second return an error ?

mycsv['Sleep'] = mycsv['Sleep'].apply(lambda x: function1(x))
```

Finally, you can add these lines on the top of `result.py`, launch the script, and pray...

```
import pandas as pd 

mycsv = pd.read_csv("your csv", encoding = "utf8")
```

Answer (score 1):

*I have found variety of different alternatives. I try to judge them to other alternatives. Pyrefine is so far the only genuine Python solution.*

### **Alternatives**

I. A partial solution [here](https://medium.com/optima-blog/semi-automated-text-cleaning-in-r-68054a9491da) to create a dictionary in R with Python to do the conversions. This does not implement GREPL edits, Jython/Python edits or Closure edits.

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python2
> #
> # Description
> #      This builds a dictionary-style structure to R with Python
> #      to do the JSON edits on other data, with only `Cluster-edit` support.    
> #
> #      The original source is (1) on which I have done some remarks.
> #
> # Further reading
> #
> # (1) Original source of the code, https://medium.com/optima-blog/semi-automated-text-cleaning-in-r-68054a9491da
> import json
> import sys
> import os
> if len(sys.argv) < 2:
>  print “USAGE: ./utils/open_refine_to_R.py [edits.json] > r_file.R”
>  exit(1)
> json_file = sys.argv[-1]
> #conversions = json.load(open(“state_clustering.json”))
> conversions = json.load(open(json_file))
> function_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(json_file))[0]
> print “%s = function(df) {“ %function_name
> for conv in conversions:
>
>   #THIS WILL fire ERRORS WITHOUT try-catch eg. with regexes
>   edits = conv[‘edits’]
>
>   columnName = str(conv[‘columnName’])
>   for edit in edits:
>     froms = edit[‘from’]
>     to = edit[‘to’]
>     for source in froms:
>       source = str(source)
>       to = str(to)
>       print “ df[df[, %s] == %s, %s] = %s” %(repr(columnName),
>         repr(source), repr(columnName), repr(to))
> print “ df”
> print “}”
> ```

where the output could be edited to Python format.

II. [P3-batchrefine](https://github.com/fusepoolP3/p3-batchrefine) is mostly coded in Java but some Python. It lets you do the transformations in the following way (not a genuine Python solution unless you are fine in calling external Java libraries).

> ./bin/batchrefine remote input.csv transform.json > output.csv

III. [Pyrefine](https://github.com/jezcope/pyrefine) is a genuine python solution and it aims to work in the following way, copied from its docs:

```
import pyrefine
import pandas as pd

with open('script.json') as script_file:
    script = pyrefine.parse(script_file)

input_data = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
output_data = script.execute(input_data)
```

### **Further Information on parsing OpenRefine JSON**

> 1. [Trying to parse a Json with Open Refine GREL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444834/trying-to-parse-a-json-with-open-refine-grel)
> 2. [Parse JSON in Google Refine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304238/parse-json-in-google-refine)
> 3. [Best way to parse a big and intricated Json file with OpenRefine (or R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715596/best-way-to-parse-a-big-and-intricated-json-file-with-openrefine-or-r)

Comment: Related ticket: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1220 Does it work well enough?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 of course but it is not that accessible as a direct R function. You have to use Python as an intermediate step to get the R thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional projects:

- https://github.com/PaulMakepeace/refine-client-py : This is a little old though
- https://github.com/opencultureconsulting/openrefine-client : This is a fork of the previous project. It extends the command line interface (CLI) and supports communication between docker containers